# Getting a WordPress form input then checking that input against API data

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I am building a form on through a WordPress plugin that accepts an order id. That id is then passed to an API then checked to make sure it's a valid ID. If the ID is valid then it outputs the status. I am new to PHP and I am not sure that the code I wrote correctly pulls the id from the form and checks against the ids within the API.

I haven't really tried anything other than the code provided

```
<?php
$orderid = $_POST["order_id"]
    private function make_tracking_request( $order_id ) {
        $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://fut.transportholdings.group/api/order-status' . $order_id . '.json' );
        try {
            // Note that we decode the body's response since it's the actual JSON feed
            $json = json_decode( $response['body'] );    
        } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
            $json = null;
        } // end try/catch
    
        if ($orderid == $order_id){
            return $json;
        }
    } // 
?>
```

I would like to check against other Ids, and if the id matches an ID in the system, then it outputs all data.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always good practice to add the code that you already worked on to give us something we can work with. SO is not a "hired coder" or "recommend a tutorial" community but we'll help if you ask about a specific problem.

Comment: You have not provided any code...

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina there actually was some code provided in the question, but it was formatted in a way that made the code impossible to see. I've edited to fix the formatting.

Comment: The above code does nothing in wordpress itself. not a post, not post status no hooks and no actions. it is probably a snippet from the API docs. can you post also the wordpress related parts ? do you have any ? also elaborate on the context of the form ..

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I wasn’t really sure how to go about this...I was using wp_remote_get which I was told was the proper function to use when getting data from an API. The form is a caldera form plugin. It collects a users name, email, and order id. If the order id matches up with one in the data base the order id along with the make and model of the users car (also in the data base and tied to the order id) is then displayed. I have little experience with PHP and APIs so any of your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I am not familiar with the specific plugin ( or API ) but I think that the API by itself  is not a problem, but understanding how WP works. I suggest you read a bit about the [wp plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API), hooks,  [Filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) and [Actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)